# help me finding the limit of sequence question

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

A 1= 1 and {A n}=root[1 + {A n-1}]

B 1= 2 and {B n}=root[2*{B n-1}]

help me

Since I am studying math recently
 I need person`s help

Answer (score 1):

So you have $a_1=1$ and $a_n=\sqrt{1+a_{n-1}}$. First, technically, we should prove that the sequence converges.  Suppose it does, then $a_n\to A$ for some $A$. If we substitute this into the relation, $A=\sqrt{1+A}$, or $A^2=1+A$. Can you solve the quadratic relation for $A$?